# Why is atprogram not working from within a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, atmel

I am working with an embedded system developed specifically for the company I work at. I want to use Atmel's command prompt to program the target processor which is pretty easy.

But, in the future, the technician building our products will do it themselves so I thought of a batch file they could run with the scrips for programming and checking the code for them automatically.

Here is the problem, I don't manage to get it running trough the *.bat file.
When I do it without I just start the Atmel console and type

```
atprogram -i ...
```

I have tried writing the batch file like:

```
"C:\...\StudioCommandPrompt.exe" atprogram -i ...
```

Which gives me the result `atprogram is neither a file nor a program`

I also tried with:

```
START "C:\...\StudioCommandPrompt.exe" atprogram -i ...
```

Then the program starts in a separate prompt, and produces the same error as above.

The empty set as suggested in the comments:

```
START "" "C:\...\StudioCommandPrompt.exe" atprogram -i ...
```

Gives the same result as without the empty set.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try: `START "" "C:\...\AtmelCommandPrompt.exe" atprogram -i`. Notice the empty set of quotes.

Comment: @Squashman, thx for your reply. The code you suggested opened a new prompt _StudioCommandPrompt_. The arguments  **atprogram -i ...** is ignored in booth prompts and focus is still in the first cmd window.

Comment: In our company the developers use AVRStudio do develop embedded software for AVR controllers. But the users in our company don't use any Atmel application to program the controllers. Instead I created a small package for the users consisting of a series of batch files for the 5 used AVR controllers and AVRdude as programming tool and Jungo drivers for the nowadays 3 used programmers (2 using USB directly, 1 via an emulated serial port). And of course I wrote a small manual how to install the drivers for the various programmers. The batch files are self-explaining.

Comment: Do not include the solution in the question, provide an answer for this instead...

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

```
START "programTool" /B /WAIT "C:\...\atprogram.exe" -i ...
```

I.E. refering to the correct software (cred: http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/just-run-programmer *hobbss*)